# Python, sets, Comparing two elements in the same set

Tags: python, set, compare

If I have a python set and I want to find out if one element in the set is part of another element in the same set, how do I do it?

I've tried using indicies but I run into the following:

```
mySet = {"hello", "lo"}
mySet[1] in mySet[0] #I expect to return true
TypeError: 'set' object does not support indexing
```

I haven't found the python docs to be particularly helpful in this situation because I don't know how to compare elements within a set.

BTW, this is my first Stackoverflow question ever.  I tried to adhere to the best practices.  If there is a way I can improve the question, please let me know.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: Sets don't provide a way to access individual items like that.  Sets are unordered, so there's no notion of the "first" element in a set.  Why are you using a set to store this data?  Some other structure may be better.

Comment: How are you getting which element in the set you want to check? Or do you want to check whether any element is part of any other element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sets don't have order. The index of an element is effectively the element itself. If you do need sets (although I have suspicions another data structure may be suitable) then they are iterable, and you can compare each element with other elements, but this won't be terrific performance wise, eg:

```
mySet = {"hello", "lo"}
for item in mySet:
    for other_item in mySet.difference([item]):
        if item in other_item:
            print item, other_item
```

Comment: not so efficient, is it? wouldn't it be better to do `for other_item in mySet:` and `if other_item is item: continue`?

Comment: @Claudiu In that case I'd go for an `itertools.product(mySet, repeat=2)` and filter out identical objects (or even possibly look at combinations/permutations) to get the most from it, but without the OP clarifying exactly why they're trying to do this it's all just a "it's technically possible, but not a great idea" kind of thing

Comment: Even better, use `itertools.combinations`.

Comment: @BrenBarn: yep was thinking that too, but I think set iteration and checking for identical object might be most efficient.

Comment: Thank you very much!  I am using a set because it's an exercise.  I'm going to read about the different methods people have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

> 'set' object does not support indexing.

That clearly states that you can not index an element of set as mySet[1].

to access a single element of a set you have to use it like mySet.pop()

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not actually trying to compare sets, but rather members of sets. The problem is you can't grab indexed members, because `set`s are an *unordered* (and as such unindexed) collection of elements.

You're trying to compare these two elements (strings). What you want is therefore a `list` or `tuple`:

```
>>> myTuple = ('hello', 'lo')
>>> myTuple[1] in myTuple[0]
True
```

This checks if the string `'lo'` is a substring of `'hello'`. This *appears* to be what you're trying to accomplish in your question.